# Why JSON.parse fail while eval() work like a charm?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

For some reason this formated JSON always fail for me when I try to use JSON.parse().

```
   let string = '[{"appearances":{"0":[138545,""],"1":[138547,""],"3":[138548,""]},"bonustrees":[240,241,264],"classs":2,"displayid":138545,"dps":18.67,"flags2":8192,"id":113965,"level":138,"name":"4Sorkas Chainfist","reqlevel":100,"slot":13,"slotbak":13,"source":[2],"sourcemore":[{"bd":1,"z":6967}],"specs":[269,581,260,263,577],"speed":2.60,"subclass":13,modes:{"mode":458752,"4":{"count":229,"outof":21731},"65536":{"count":28,"outof":4490},"131072":{"count":18,"outof":4719},"262144":{"count":183,"outof":3517}},count:229,stack:[1,1]}]';

   console.log(eval(string)); // Output as expected from JSON.parse
   console.log(JSON.parse(string)); // SyntaxError: Unexpected token m in JSON at position 341
```

Comment: `,count:229,stack:` at the end is not valid JSON without `"`

Comment: your string is not correctly stringified for JSON.parse to parse

Comment: Because it's not valid JSON. Voting to close as typo/non-repro/not-useful-to-others-in-future. In JSON, property names (keys) must be in double quotes. You have `modes: {` (no quotes around it). See http://json.org and http://jsonlint.com

Comment: Put double quotes around `modes`, `count` and `stack` to make it a valid JSON.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`JSON.parse` fails because it can only process JSON syntax. Your string is not a valid JSON -- it says so in the error message you're receiving.

The error points to an `m` from the `modes` from this part:

```
"subclass":13,modes:{"mode":458752,
```

You've also got a couple of more quotes missing down the line; you might want to check that out.

---

`eval` executes JavaScript code passed in as  a string -- as if you've written it in code in the place where you're running the function. Since your string is valid JavaScript, it works without a problem.

Comment: @AmardeepBhowmick `eval()` just runs JS code, it is not a JSON parser.

Comment: @AmardeepBhowmick I've updated the answer with the explanation.